# How can I manipulate strings in JSX?

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, jsx

I have a string in a JSX file that I have to manipulate this way:

Let's suppose I have the following string with this value `medical_specialty = "Plastic Surgery"`

I need to do this:

```
medical_specialty.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase()
```

to transform it to `plastic-surgery`

Do I have full JavaScript syntax in JSX files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sysntax in JSX files.
For example, using react:

```
  render() {
    let medical_specialty = "Plastic Surgery"

    medical_specialty = medical_specialty.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase()

    return (
        <div>
            { medical_specialty }
        </div>
    )
  }
```

As Dave Newton said, JSX is nothing more than a reprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript.

Comment: I've tried exactly that into the render() method but I get this error `code` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.       It is probably that the object I am referencing it is not bound yet when this is interpreted...

Answer (score 0):

JSX is nothing more than JavaScript plus an XML-ish syntax extension.

I'm not sure how you'd be writing JSX without using JS already, e.g., via ES6 classes, the old-style `createClass` method, etc. Clearly it's JavaScript, and any trivial web search will tell you exactly what JSX is:

> JSX is a preprocessor step that adds XML syntax to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is a syntax that is being transformed into **pure JavaScript ** (e.g. by babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx).

So you cannot manipulate the actual JSX (like you would do with **true** XML, which will be parsed using something like XMLDOM) because the JSX itself is never resolved into a string at runtime, it's actually code.

Anything in curly braces is tagged as a section that will **not** be transformed, so you can have whatever you want there, as long as it matches the rest of JSX flow (all of which will end up as JS code, including any compile or run-time errors in it).

For example, this:

```
    <SomeComponent someAttr="value">
        <SomeSubComponent/>
    </SomeComponent>;
```

Will be transformed into

```
    React.createElement(
        SomeComponent,
        { someAttr: "value" },
        React.createElement(SomeSubComponent, null)
    );
```

Look at [Babel online compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=%3CSomeComponent%20someAttr%3D%22value%22%3E%0A%20%20%3CSomeSubComponent%2F%3E%0A%3C%2FSomeComponent%3E%3B%0A) in order to expirement!

Have a nice coding day ;-)